# Hide the two text selection helpers in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

This is what i mean by "two little text selection helpers in mobile". They appear when the user releases touch after selecting

(I dont know what thay are called exactly)

I am making a website where they will be hidden if the user is on a mobile and is selecting any text

Like this (u will see these hidden for example in replit.com):
[image]

(Screenshot taken in mobile and i have released my touch)

I am aware of the css `::selection` property but i am unable to solve this problem

How do i do this?

Comment: You can't. It's outside of the browser. It's part of the device UI, which you have no access to from the page. Not really sure, but it might be reactive to the `::selection` color, coming from the page. [Play with it](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/).

Comment: But in replit.com u can clearly see it!! I think the trick is to get the selection position and **highlight** text from there....

Comment: You can see them ***on any website which allows text selection*** if your device + browser combo uses that type of selection. But you won't see them ***on any website***, on another OS + browser combo. Because, again, they are not part of the page. They are part of the device UI.